# NyquistPlot creates misleading connections with some plot range

Tags: plotting, functions

This Nyquist plot depicts a plot range aiming to cover all crucial curve characteristics.

```
NyquistPlot[(2 (7 + s)^2)/(s (1 + s)^2), 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{-1, 0}]}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-30, 2}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]
However, when I narrow the plot range to, for example, `{{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}`, the curve becomes incorrect and misleading, particularly in the connection between the dashed and solid lines. Is this expected? Is there a way to fix this for the given plot range?
I want to reduce the plot range to better observe the enclosure of the Nyquist plot around the critical point -1 + 0j. However, when I decrease the plot range, the Nyquist curve becomes inaccurate.

```
NyquistPlot[(2 (7 + s)^2)/(s (1 + s)^2), 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{-1, 0}]}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

The correct version should be something like this.

[image]

Comment: add the option `PlotPoints -> 200`?

Comment: @kglr the connection is still wrong if you compare which dash branch connected with which solid branch between the full version on top and the narrow version at the bottom.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Report it to support@wolfram.com.